# How to 'group' docmd.runsql SQL (MS ACCESS) into transactions and allow rollback on failure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I need to perform multiple SQL statements (INSERT, UPDATE etc...), but if it fails at any point, to roll them all back.

I typically use docmd.runsql "INSERT INTO..."

How can I implement transactions.

Answer (score 2):

From [How to: Use Transactions in a DAO Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243806(v=office.12).aspx). depending on your queries, it may not be possible to run all of them within the one transaction in MS Access.

```
Sub ChangeTitle()

Dim wrkCurrent As DAO.Workspace
Dim dbsNorthwind As DAO.Database
Dim rstEmployee As DAO.Recordset

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   Set wrkCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
   Set dbsNorthwind = CurrentDB
   Set rstEmployee = dbsNorthwind.OpenRecordset("Employees")

   wrkCurrent.BeginTrans
   Do Until rstEmployee.EOF
      If rstEmployee!Title = "Sales Representative" Then
         rstEmployee.Edit
         rstEmloyee!Title = "Sales Associate"
         rstEmployee.Update
      End If
      rstEmployee.MoveNext
   Loop

   If MsgBox("Save all changes?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
      wrkCurrent.CommitTrans
   Else
      wrkCurrent.Rollback
   End If

   rstEmployee.Close
   dbsNorthwind.Close
   wrkCurrent.Close

   Set rstEmployee = nothing
   Set dbsNorthwind = Nothing
   Set wrkCurrent = Nothing

   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

[Other posts on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms+access%5D+transactions)

Further information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208950(v=office.12).aspx

```
With queries

Sub RunQueries()
On Error GoTo errtrap

'Set up all the declarations and begin the transactions
Dim wks As DAO.Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sSQL As String

Set wks = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = CurrentDb

wks.BeginTrans

sSQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET AText = 'P'"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

db.Execute "Query1", dbFailOnError

'This will fail
sSQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET ANumber = 'P'"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

wks.CommitTrans

exithere:

db.Close
wks.Close
Exit Sub

errtrap:

' Something happened so all the queries are not committed
wks.Rollback
GoTo exithere

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not using recordsets, I'm just doing multiple "DOCMD.RUNSQL INSERT INTO TBLA....".

Comment: It is the same idea, but I suggest you use `Set db=CurrentDB: db.Execute "Insert ..."

Comment: +1 Really good example of using the workspace, I also second the use of .Execute over DoCmd.RunSQL

Comment: That's great, works a charm, if you want to update your answer, I'll accept it?